# How can I prevent my iPhone app from downloading on an iPad?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, app-store-connect, download, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have developed a game with cocos2d-x 3 for iPhone. My game does not function properly on an iPad, so I'm wondering if I can prevent iPads from downloading my app from the AppStore?

Comment: See "Setting the Target iOS Devices" in [the official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW1). Found by a simple search.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it is possible to prevent an iOS application from being installed on an iPad. An app which is an iPad only app will not be installable on an iPhone, but a universal or iPhone app is installable on both iPhone and iPad device families.

You will need to make your app function correctly on iPad devices or it will most likely be rejected when submitted to the app store